# Cloud Firestore Queries in Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

How to query (in cloud functions) on other documents when a new document was stored in cloud firestore. Can I follow the same approach that docs say to query data in client side.

I got the following error:
`Error: Cannot encode type ([object Undefined]) to a Firestore Value`

Comment: Yes you can. Have you even tried?

Comment: Your error is related to a wrong write, not a read. The error is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to follow transactions in cloud firestore to implement the above plan.One need to use transactions because the two actions must happen at the same time,like reading from 1 document and updating the other document simultaneously.